# How to solve the problem 'Could not create windows registry node' with Preferences class in Java?

Tags: java, preferences

I'm trying to use the Preferences class to store some information. Here is the code:

```java
package association;

import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class Association {

    Preferences prefs=Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(Association.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Association temp=new Association();
        String s=temp.prefs.get("name","");
    }
    
}
```

But whenever I run the code it shows that-

```
Jul 27, 2022 1:41:17 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not create windows registry node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\association at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Jul 27, 2022 1:41:17 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences WindowsRegOpenKey1

WARNING: Trying to recreate Windows registry node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\association at root 0x80000002.
Jul 27, 2022 1:41:17 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences openKey

WARNING: Could not open windows registry node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs\association at root 0x80000002. Windows RegOpenKey(...) returned error code 2.
```

I've opened regedit and found that 'Prefs' key exists in

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\

Then I've created a 'Prefs' key in

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft\

but it doesn't work. How to solve this?